# I have just started on MEAN stack. I was trying to store my form submit data to mongo database but I have been unable to do so

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
var Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    uname: String,
    upno: Number,
    umno: Number,
    ul1: String,
    l2: String,
    ul3: String
});
var user = mongoose.model('emp', Schema);
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/" + "assign.html");
});
app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    new user({
        uname: req.body.username,
        upno: req.body.uphno,
        umno: req.body.umbno,
        ul1: req.body.l1,
        ul2: req.body.l2,
        ul3: req.body.l3
    }).save(function (err, doc) {
        if (err) res.json(err);
        else    res.send('Successfully inserted!');
    });
});
app.listen(8086, function () {
    console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8086/');
});
```

I am getting this error:

> C:\Users\hp pc\WebstormProjects\MyForm2\node_modules\mongodb\lib\server.js:242
>           process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
>                                         ^
>    Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
>       at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
>       at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:893:20)
>       at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1062:14)

Comment: Too much code. Please strip it down to the essential parts. And please let us know exactely what your issue is.

Comment: I'm  sorry for that. Hope that you can understand it now.

Comment: The error message is pretty self explanatory. Is there a MongoDB running at 127.0.0.1:27017?

Comment: if i have not explicitly passed it, shouldn't it be running at that port by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicate that you didn't start Mongo server. Make sure you start it first by running `mongod` in your command prompt or terminal.

Comment: thanx man it worked. I was starting it via the .exe in the bin folder and it wasnt working. Now i did started it via command prompt and set the dbpath and worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Your mongoDB server isn't launched, so you can start it using .exe file or `mongod` command if your path is set.